# Is there any way to alter security settings of newest version of Wordpad to prevent showing the message about blocked content?

Tags: rtf, wordpad

In the latest version of Windows 10 (1903), a security protection has been added to Wordpad. When there is some specific content in the document, it is blocked and the document is marked as not trusted - a warning message is shown when trying to open.

- *Security warning*

  **Some content is blocked**

  Some content of this document has been blocked because the source of
  this document might not be trusted. If you trust the source of this
  document, click Unblock to show all content.

  [Unblock (Show all content)] [Ok (Don't show blocked content)]

It is possible to show all content, but the Wordpad propmpts always, even for the same file opened again. When clicked on OK (Don't show blocked content), a following message is being displayed:

- *Windows Security Warning*

  This document contains code that your security settings do not allow,
  so it might not display correctly

I exactly know what content is being blocked in my case. In the software I use, when the user creates a report, the applications fills a RTF template with values and images. These images are inserted using the /pngblip command, that is followed by image data.

```
'{\pict\pngblip' + '\picwgoal' + imgWidth + '\pichgoal' + imgHeight
```

That is the issue, because it seems to be a deprecated option, that is currently marked as insecure.

This settings was used to ensure compatibility across Wordpad and Microsoft Word. Currently I am looking for some alternatives that could provide similar functionality. An attempt has been made to use a WMF format to wrap the png image, but it is currently diplayed blurred in Microsoft Word (2010), so the used method needs further development.

Meanwhile I am looking for an option to disable this new security feature of Wordpad, at least for files from certrain directories. **Is there any way to alter this behaviour?** I even tried to change Internet Settings, because I thought it may be related to ActiveX settings, but with no effect.